# Is the header comparison in vertx web case sensitive

Tags: http, http-headers, vert.x

I have a vertx web routers defined as follows:

```
    router.route(POST, "/customers")
            .consumes("application/json;charset=utf-8")
            .handler { runHandler(it) }
```

When I hit this route, I am getting a 404 error with header set as:

```
       Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

It works for header:

```
      Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

This beg the question whether the header value comparison is case sensitive. Is this the standard or an implementation issue with vertx web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Field values in general are case-sensitive. However, the charset parameter value is not, so it shouldn't matter (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.3.1.1.2)

2) That said: there is no "charset" parameter on application/json anyway, so just get rid of it (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc8259.html#rfc.section.11)

Comment: About point #1, the Content-Type RFC says otherwise: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-5.1

5.1.  Syntax of the Content-Type Header Field
```
     content := "Content-Type" ":" type "/" subtype
                *(";" parameter)
                ; Matching of media type and subtype
                ; is ALWAYS case-insensitive.
```

Comment: @DanielMarcotte - a) that's Content-Type in MIME, not HTTP, so that RFC is entirely irrelevant, b) the discussion is about parameter values, not type or subtype.

Comment: @JulianReschke My link was not good you're right. However, the HTTP 1.1 RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) states that Media Types of Content-Type are case-insensitive. Here's the Media Type RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1

Quote:
   For example, the following examples are all equivalent, but the first is preferred for consistency:

     text/html;charset=utf-8
     text/html;charset=UTF-8
     Text/HTML;Charset="utf-8"
     text/html; charset="utf-8"


The behavior is clearly not this one in Vertx, as of 3.5.1

Comment: And we disagree where...?

Comment: well in the fact that "it shouldn't matter" but it was since there was a bug in vertx (fixed in 3.6.0) I guess the problem was that this question has been asked instead of being posted as a bug in vertx-web at the very beginning. ;-)

Comment: FWIW, the other bug  would be expecting a charset parameter on a media type which doesn't even define it.